# Let $G$ be a semigroup, prove the following statement

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

> Let G be a semigroup with the following property: For any $a \in G$, there exist a unique $a^t\in G$ such that
>   $aa^ta = a$, show that
>
> If $x,a \in G$ and $a^tx = a^t$, then $x = aa^t$.

**My thoughts**

I can't think much about this question because I can barely understand it.
It says, "For any a ∈ $G$", So any element of $G$ can be thought as an $a$.
If $a^t$ is an element, so I can say $a^t$ is also an $a$ element of $G$, as it is an $a$ element, There will be another $a^t$ and so on.... Therefore I can say that $G$is infinite.

But the question treats a and x are distinct elements, and then associate x by saying that $x = aa^t$.

I'm totally confused, I'm not sure whether what I'm thinking is right, but I'm new to group theory, any help is appreciated.

Comment: $a^t$ is the so-called pseudo-inverse. They are just saying that every element has a pseudo-inverse. As such, $(a^t)^t$ tends to be $a$ itself, so your infinite chain of elements might just be a loop.

Comment: You can show that $a^taa^t = a^t$ so the inverse of $a^t$ is $a$.

Comment: About "Therefore I can say that $G$ is infinite": No, that doesn't follow. The elements you described ($a,a^t,(a^t)^t,((a^t)^t)^t,\dots)$ might not all be distinct.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Why ? The question says every $a$ in $G$ has a $a^t$, why can't I assume that $a^t = a$ ?

Comment: @hjx You cannot make that assumption because $a^t$ must satisfy the condition $aa^ta=a$ which $a$ may not (probablly won't) satisfy.

Comment: $a^t$ is not necessarily distinct from $a$.  So the group is not necessarily infinite.

Comment: The equality $a^t=a$ can occur only rarely, because, as @JimH pointed out, it would require $aaa=a$. But $(a^t)^t=a$ occurs more often; in fact, if $G$ happens to be a group, then all its elements satisfy $(a^t)^t=a$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass In fact for any $a$, $aa^t$ is idempotent, so every element of the form $aa^t$ is its own (pseudo) inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $aa^ta=a$ and $a^tx=a^t$.

Thus, $$(aa^t)(aa^t)(aa^t)=(aa^ta)(a^taa^t)=$$
$$=a(a^taa^t)=(aa^ta)a^t=aa^t$$ and 
$$(aa^t)x(aa^t)=a(a^tx)(aa^t)=aa^t(aa^t)=$$
$$=(aa^ta)a^t=aa^t.$$
Thus, since for $aa^t$ there is an unique $b$ for which $(aa^t)b(aa^t)=aa^t$, we obtain $$x=aa^t$$ and we are done!

Comment: It seems that the two statements you gave are only strong enough to show that $a^tx=a^taa^t$. From here, how does one get rid of the initial $a^t$?

Comment: @Christian Woll I fixed my post. See now please.

Comment: You've only shown that $x = aa^t$ satisfies the equality.  The goal is to show that $x$ must equal $aa^t$.

Comment: I think that you have done much of what I suggested though you didn't describe it.  Your first line shows that $aa^t$ is its own inverse.  I think your second line shows that $x$ is the inverse of  $aa^t$.  Uniqueness allow you to draw the conclusion.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think you have all the legos there, you just need to stick them together.

Comment: @hjx What do you think about my proof? Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Although your answer is right, I can't understand it. If you can explain your thoughts in a more detailed way It would be of great help for me since I'm beginning in this subject.

Comment: @hjx Is the first line in my proof clear?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg No, I made an effort to understand, but without words to describe what you did is a bit difficult.

Comment: @hjx I added something. See now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks for the help, I'll spend a time trying to understand.

Comment: @hjx Good luck! I am ready to explain more.

Answer (score 2):

The general set-up means:
For each and every element of $G$, call the element of interest $a$, there is an element of $G$, called $a^t$ (because it depends of $a$) such that $aa^ta=a$ and for each $a$, there is only one $a^t$ that works.
(This tells us that $G$ is an inverse semigroup.)

You are asked to suppose that for some $a$ in $G$, and some $x$ of $G$, we have $a^tx=a^t$, then it will turn out that $x = aa^t$.

I was taught to call $a^t$ the (von Neumann) inverse of $a$ -- it is NOT a group inverse.
One way to proceed: show that $aa^t$ is its own inverse.  Then show that $x$ is an inverse of $aa^t$.  Use uniqueness to draw the desired conclusion.

Comment: Thanks, now it is clearer. I've read several books about group theory and none mentioned anything about semigroups. Is there any book you recommend for a beginner ?

Comment: @hjx  I'm sorry, but I haven't read a book on semigroups.  I studied with a semigroup theorist in graduate school 30 years ago.  He used lecture notes only.

Comment: I thought the notation of an inverse of an element was $a^{-1}$, I thought the $t$ was a parameter.

Comment: Yes, $a^-1$ is sometimes (or often) used for pseudo-inverses.  In a book that will be focused on group theory, the author probably wanted to avoid confusion with the group inverse.  Note that we cannot conclude that $aa^t$ simplifies to $1$.  In fact the semigroup may not even have an identity.